# How to connect go-admin to Postgres database?

Tags: go, go-gin

According to the docs of [go-admin](https://book.go-admin.cn/en/quick_start) I have created a configuration for admin panel extension and Postgres database. I use Docker containers, so host is set to "db". The error is displayed while trying to get home endpoint. I have found nothing in docs about "goadmin_session" and have no idea how to correct this error.

```
cfg := config.Config{
    Databases: config.DatabaseList{
        "default": {
            Host:         "db",
            Port:         "5432",
            User:         "gorm",
            Pwd:          "gorm",
            Name:         "gorm_db",
            MaxIdleConns: 50,
            MaxOpenConns: 150,
            Driver:       "postgresql",
        },
    },
    UrlPrefix: "admin", // The url prefix of the website.
        // Store must be set and guaranteed to have write access, otherwise new administrator users cannot be added.
    Store: config.Store{
        Path:   "./uploads",
        Prefix: "uploads",
    },
    Language: language.EN,
}
```

Here is a traceback:

```
engine/engine.go:402    =====> Initialize database connections
2023-03-30T09:49:43.715842137Z 检查 pg 配置 host=db port=5432 user=gorm password=gorm dbname=gorm_db sslmode=disable
2023-03-30T09:49:43.736955435Z Database connection closed
2023-03-30T09:49:43.739423928Z panic: pq: relation "goadmin_session" does not exist
2023-03-30T09:49:43.739453429Z 
2023-03-30T09:49:43.739462206Z goroutine 1 [running]:
2023-03-30T09:49:43.739469476Z github.com/GoAdminGroup/go-admin/modules/db.CommonQuery(0x14d2600?, {0xc00045b840?, 0x1630314?}, {0xc000277220?, 0x0?, 0x0?})
2023-03-30T09:49:43.739641400Z  /go/pkg/mod/github.com/!go!admin!group/go-admin@v1.2.24/modules/db/performer.go:20 +0x676
2023-03-30T09:49:43.739652103Z github.com/GoAdminGroup/go-admin/modules/db.(*Postgresql).QueryWithConnection(0xc0002b61e0, {0x1630314, 0x7}, {0xc00045b800?, 0x8a29a8?}, {0xc000277220, 0x1, 0x1})
2023-03-30T09:49:43.739659429Z  /go/pkg/mod/github.com/!go!admin!group/go-admin@v1.2.24/modules/db/postgresql.go:52 +0x9e
2023-03-30T09:49:43.739665812Z github.com/GoAdminGroup/go-admin/modules/db.(*Postgresql).QueryWith(0x7fedcc37b768?, 0x7fedf3f0f5b8?, {0x1630314?, 0xc000080400?}, {0xc00045b800?, 0x0?}, {0xc000277220?, 0x8e4916?, 0x10?})
2023-03-30T09:49:43.739672840Z  /go/pkg/mod/github.com/!go!admin!group/go-admin@v1.2.24/modules/db/postgresql.go:74 +0x65
2023-03-30T09:49:43.739678702Z github.com/GoAdminGroup/go-admin/modules/db.(*SQL).All(0xc000442b40)
2023-03-30T09:49:43.739699812Z  /go/pkg/mod/github.com/!go!admin!group/go-admin@v1.2.24/modules/db/statement.go:442 +0x102
2023-03-30T09:49:43.740099312Z github.com/GoAdminGroup/go-admin/modules/auth.InitCSRFTokenSrv({0x1b87c70?, 0xc0002b61e0})
2023-03-30T09:49:43.740116344Z  /go/pkg/mod/github.com/!go!admin!group/go-admin@v1.2.24/modules/auth/auth.go:94 +0x235
2023-03-30T09:49:43.740123217Z github.com/GoAdminGroup/go-admin/engine.(*Engine).Use(0xc00010b360, {0x160c380, 0xc0004b4820})
2023-03-30T09:49:43.740134285Z  /go/pkg/mod/github.com/!go!admin!group/go-admin@v1.2.24/engine/engine.go:72 +0xf3
2023-03-30T09:49:43.740140103Z main.main()
2023-03-30T09:49:43.740145212Z  /app/app/main/main.go:57 +0x37d
```

Comment: Have you initialized the `gorm_db` database with https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoAdminGroup/go-admin/master/data/admin.pgsql?

Comment: I didn't do this. Why so?

Comment: See the doc here: https://book.go-admin.cn/en/install